# wit.ai support for languages other than English

Tags: wit.ai

I just start playing with [wit.ai](https://wit.ai) NLP and Bot Engine but found some difficulties to make it running using the Polish language.

Especially the built-in entities/functions (like wit/number or wit/age-of-person) seem not to work at all.

So here is my question - Does it make any sense to use wit.ai for languages other than English?

or

Can I verify if wit.ai is trained for any particular language?

Answer (score 4):

Good question!  Wit currently supports 50 languages: https://wit.ai/blog/2016/04/28/new-languages. Some of them are in Beta like Polish.

- Wit relies heavily on machine learning for built-in entities like wit/location. So the more Polish apps (ie more validated expressions) the better it will be.
- For some built-in entities like wit/datetime, wit/duration, wit/age-of-person, Wit uses a probabilistic parser that we open sourced here: [duckling.wit.ai](https://duckling.wit.ai/)

Any help from the community is more than welcome... So if you want to participate, don't hesitate to look at the [repo](https://github.com/wit-ai/duckling) and check if your language is covered or needs improvement

Comment: The point is what does the "supports" mean. We had finally got a simple Polish story running (using some wit/xxxx entities) - but we had to wait  about a day (!) to get "green light" and expected behavior...